# 500 server error while registration with OpenID

Tags: database, django, openid, osqa

I deployed a Q&A site using [OSQA](http://osqa.net/). I have a problem with OpenID. When I click on a provider to register new user (i.e. google), osqa redirects me to google to confirm my email address. Then I came back to osqa, it asks for a username and password. In next step I get 500 server error and registration fails. I can register new user with normal registration form and login without any problem.

Here are last lines of /log/django.osqa.log:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.3-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py TIME: 2013-06-01 00:40:52,772 MSG: base.py:handle_uncaught_exception:209 Internal Server Error: /account/register/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.3-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 111, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/osqa/osqa-server/forum/views/auth.py", line 159, in external_register
    if form1.is_valid():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.3-py2.7.egg/django/forms/forms.py", line 121, in is_valid
    return self.is_bound and not bool(self.errors)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.3-py2.7.egg/django/forms/forms.py", line 112, in _get_errors
    self.full_clean()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.3-py2.7.egg/django/forms/forms.py", line 267, in full_clean
    self._clean_fields()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.3-py2.7.egg/django/forms/forms.py", line 284, in _clean_fields
    value = field.clean(value)
  File "/home/osqa/osqa-server/forum/forms/general.py", line 151, in clean
    return super(UserRealNameField, self).clean(real_name)
  File "/home/osqa/osqa-server/forum/forms/general.py", line 27, in clean
    value = value.strip()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'
/home/osqa/osqa-server/forum/views/meta.py TIME: 2013-06-01 00:40:52,777 MSG: meta.py:error_handler:200 
        error executing request:
        PATH: /account/register/
        USER: <anonymous>
        METHOD: POST
        POST PARAMETERS:
                username: asbol
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: 3204ab843f346dd595302ae4910ea26d
        email: asbolasbol@gmail.com
        bnewaccount: Create Account
        next: /

        GET PARAMETERS:
        None
        HTTP HEADERS:
                mod_wsgi.listener_port: 80
        HTTP_REFERER: http://domain/account/register/
        mod_wsgi.listener_host: 
        SERVER_SOFTWARE: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
        SCRIPT_NAME: 
        mod_wsgi.handler_script: 
        SERVER_SIGNATURE: <address>Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at domain Port 80</address>

        REQUEST_METHOD: POST
        PATH_INFO: /account/register/
        HTTP_ORIGIN: http://domain
        SERVER_PROTOCOL: HTTP/1.1
        QUERY_STRING: 
        CONTENT_LENGTH: 221
        HTTP_USER_AGENT: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.94 Safari/537.36
        HTTP_CONNECTION: keep-alive
        HTTP_COOKIE: __atuvc=1%7C22; greeting_set=True; csrftoken=3204ab843f346dd595302ae4910ea26d; sessionid=c59f00fd45976880b724074376627286
        SERVER_NAME: domain
        REMOTE_ADDR: 5.63.149.98
        mod_wsgi.request_handler: wsgi-script
        wsgi.url_scheme: http
        PATH_TRANSLATED: /home/osqa/osqa-server/osqa.wsgi/account/register/
        SERVER_PORT: 80
        wsgi.multiprocess: False
        mod_wsgi.input_chunked: 0
        SERVER_ADDR: IP
        DOCUMENT_ROOT: /home/osqa/osqa-server
        mod_wsgi.process_group: OSQA
        SCRIPT_FILENAME: /home/osqa/osqa-server/osqa.wsgi
        SERVER_ADMIN: admin@domain
        wsgi.input: <mod_wsgi.Input object at 0x7f40b05e6870>
        HTTP_HOST: domain
        wsgi.multithread: True
        mod_wsgi.callable_object: application
        HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL: max-age=0
        REQUEST_URI: /account/register/
        HTTP_ACCEPT: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
        wsgi.version: (1, 1)
        GATEWAY_INTERFACE: CGI/1.1
        wsgi.run_once: False
        wsgi.errors: <mod_wsgi.Log object at 0x7f40b9e83a30>
        REMOTE_PORT: 55121
        HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE: en-US,en;q=0.8
        mod_wsgi.version: (3, 3)
        CONTENT_TYPE: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
        mod_wsgi.application_group: domain|
        mod_wsgi.script_reloading: 1
        wsgi.file_wrapper: <built-in method file_wrapper of mod_wsgi.Adapter object at 0x7f40b065aaf8>
        CSRF_COOKIE: 3204ab843f346dd595302ae4910ea26d
        HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING: gzip,deflate,sdch

        COOKIES:
                __atuvc: 1%7C22
        csrftoken: 3204ab843f346dd595302ae4910ea26d
        sessionid: c59f00fd45976880b724074376627286
        greeting_set: True

        EXCEPTION INFO:
                Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.3-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 111, in get_response
            response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
          File "/home/osqa/osqa-server/forum/views/auth.py", line 159, in external_register
            if form1.is_valid():
          File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.3-py2.7.egg/django/forms/forms.py", line 121, in is_valid
            return self.is_bound and not bool(self.errors)
          File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.3-py2.7.egg/django/forms/forms.py", line 112, in _get_errors
            self.full_clean()
          File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.3-py2.7.egg/django/forms/forms.py", line 267, in full_clean
            self._clean_fields()
          File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.3-py2.7.egg/django/forms/forms.py", line 284, in _clean_fields
            value = field.clean(value)
          File "/home/osqa/osqa-server/forum/forms/general.py", line 151, in clean
            return super(UserRealNameField, self).clean(real_name)
          File "/home/osqa/osqa-server/forum/forms/general.py", line 27, in clean
            value = value.strip()
        AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: You need to give us more information. What's the traceback for the 500 error?

Comment: I've just added error log from /log/django.osqa.log .